# Ignoring NaN values Vertica SQL

Tags: sql, nan, vertica

Is there a way to check for NaN values and ignore them in vertica SQL?

Answer (score 1):

A predicate must be used as such:

```
dbadmin=> SELECT * FROM tbl;
  a
-----
 NaN
   1
   2
(3 rows)

dbadmin=> SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a <> a;
  a
-----
 NaN
(1 row)

dbadmin=> SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = a;
 a
---
 1
 2
(2 rows)
```

`WHERE a = 'NaN'` cannot be true by definition.

See my [blog post](http://vertica.tips/2015/07/22/quick-tip-ignoring-nan-values/) for more.